# How to use the '-config' option of `setxkbmap`?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a keymap file with this content:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete+numpad(shift3)"   };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "macintosh_vndr/apple(alukbd)+macintosh_vndr/us+inet(evdev)+altwin(swap_alt_win)+capslock(backspace)+compose(rctrl)+macintosh_vndr/apple(alupckeys)+shift(both_capslock)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "macintosh(applealu_ansi)"  };
};
```

I thought I can load it with `setxkbmap -config keymap`, but I can't.

How are you supposed to use '-config'? How to load a xkb_keymap section?

*Edit:* I know that I can load it with `xkbcomp keymap :0`, but still: how does '-config' work?

*Edit2:* That's the output I get:

```
$ setxkbmap -v 10 -config ~/xkb/keymap 
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Found file /home/user/xkb/keymap
Couldn't find configuration file "/home/user/xkb/keymap"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-config file
       Specifies the name of an XKB configuration
       file which describes the keyboard to be used.
```

I think this dates back from the time of [`xf86cfg`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.2/xf86cfg.1.html). When starting `X` on multiple VTs one could have different keyboard configurations with per-server keyboard config files:

```
<Xroot>/lib/X11/xkb/X0-config.keyboard
<Xroot>/lib/X11/xkb/X1-config.keyboard
```

---

A keyboard configuration file consists of `key = value` pairs, one per line. Here is my rather simple test file, `/home/don/my-config.keyboard`:

```
Rules    =  "xorg"
Model    =  "pc104"
Layout   =  "fr"
Variant  =  "dvorak"
Options  =  "grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps"
```

load it with `setxkbmap`:

```
setxkbmap -config /home/don/my-config.keyboard
```

and voilà:

```
setxkbmap -query
```

returns:

```
rules:      xorg
model:      pc104
layout:     fr
variant:    dvorak
options:    grp:caps_toggle,grp_led:caps
```

Comment: When running from command-line, we can give `setxkbmap -option` to reset all options set before. How can I achieve this in the configuration file? I tried giving just `Options =` and `Options = ""`. The former throws an error and the latter doesn't work.

Comment: @Hashken - I don't think the config file could reset the configuration to default. It's purpose is to load a keyboard configuration and that's all it does. However, if you load a config file after another one then yes, the options in the second file will not overwrite the old ones but will be added to the existing ones. I guess one way to avoid that would be to prepend your options with a _comma_ e.g. `Options = ",grp:alt_shift_toggle"` or use `Options = ","` to delete the old ones and load none.

Comment: Hmm.. Makes sense. I also tried having several `Options` lines so as to have one setting per line. This is pretty useful to have comments on the side explaining the function. But unfortunately, if multiple `Options` line are given, only the last seems to take effect. Is there a way to give different Options in different lines? Also, where I can refer for the complete format of this configuration file?

Comment: @Hashken - the only documentation that I know of is this [page](http://pascal.tsu.ru/en/xkb/config.html)

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer is the accepted one. This answers: **How do I best load my own XKB configuration?**

```
xkbcomp -I$HOME/xkb ~/xkb/keymap $DISPLAY
```

The `keymap` file is in the format of the OP (i.e. me). In `~/xkb` I have subdirectories like `keycodes` and `symbols` which contain the extra files I references in `keymap`.