# Adding a rule file to xkb

Tags: xkb

I expected that with the file ~/.xkb/rules/myr as follows

```
! option        = symbols
  test      = +what(ever)
```

then the output of `setxkbmap -I$HOME/.xkb -rules myr -option test
-print` would reflect the test rule, but insted I see

```
Couldn't find rules file (myr)
```

What am I missing?

PS.  I don't think the other answer helps.  If I use a config file to
specify the rule file, I still get the message that it couldn't be found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the '-config' option of \`setxkbmap\`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167131/how-to-use-the-config-option-of-setxkbmap)

Comment: @Bart, I don't think so.